# Cannot resolve symbol '@style/AppTheme' in android manifest

Tags: java, android

[image: Android Manifest code]

The error message is "Cannot resolve symbol '@style/AppTheme'"

Here is the 2nd problem. [image: Android resource linking failed]

Comment: Can you post your `styles.xml` file?

Comment: @luca_999 Here is the link https://imgur.com/a/SIZRKSQ

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own `AppTheme` in the `values/styles.xml` file, for example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Can you please open this link because I will get the same result when I type values/styles.xml? https://imgur.com/a/SIZRKSQ. Can you tell me which one I am looking for in search box?

Comment: There are styles from Android SDK listed in the screenshot (they are readonly, BTW). You should create new, project-specific file `styles.xml` in `res/values` folder (I assume, there is no one, as AS does not include in in the search results)

Comment: What happened if I don't have styles in folder (Android studio project)  but I have 4 different names in res/values, which are attrs, colors, strings and theme

Comment: You could create new file `styles.sml` or add AppTheme style in `theme.xml`. These files are common place for theme, styles, appearance references

Comment: In theme.XML the code is                                                                                     
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="green">Green</string>
</resources>

Comment: Just add code from my answer into that file (inside `<resources>`, of course) and rebuild the project.

Comment: in themes.xml I put "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <string name="green">Green</string>
</resources>"